# Can I disable spellcheck and capitalization using apps-script?

Tags: google-apps-script, spell-checking

is it possible to:

1. switch of capitalization of sentences
2. switch off spell check
   with Apps Script? We'd like to create an add on that turns off these elements fo preparing kids for NAPLAN testing, where the NAP application doesn't run these features. We'd like to prepare them so they are used to having to do this for themselves, rather than relying on the application to do it for them.

When they've finished preparation, ideally they'd click the button again, and all features would be restored.

I can't find a property in the Reference Guide

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to get or set the user preferences with either DocumentApp or the Docs API.  There is also no way to record a macro in Google Docs.  Removing the "Automatically capitalize words" preference is fairly easy to do manually.  It is the first item in the list of Tools -> preferences.

Comment: Thanks. Aware of manually changing - looking to make it really easy for early years teachers.